# How to reload multiple HTML elements with one 'GET' method

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Here is part of my code:

```
function x(action) {
    if (action == 'reload') {
        $("#a").load(" #a > *");
        $("#b").load(" #b > *");
        $("#c").load(" #c > *");
        $("#d").load(" #d > *");
    }
}
```

I want these #a,#b,#c,#d elements reload themselves after some actions. My code is working but I get multiple same GET records in my backend everytime I trigger the function, like this:

```
[07/Mar/2021 01:09:02] "GET /xxx/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12250
[07/Mar/2021 01:09:02] "GET /xxx/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12250
[07/Mar/2021 01:09:02] "GET /xxx/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12250
[07/Mar/2021 01:09:02] "GET /xxx/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12250
```

I wonder if there is an easy way to reload these elements by using 'GET' method only once, and without using `location.reload()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is jquery load method you are using.

the thing is, for every time you call the load method, that is a different get request be made.

remember django get function is backend code, unless you want to make one ajax get request and then make your chanages, there is not much you can do.

you could return a json data from the get request on django and then use the data to effect your change.

try using:

```
$.get(url, function(data){
    $("#b").html(data['b'])
    ........
})
```